# display pdf in mvc 3 resides on azure server. Which is best way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am using Asp.net mvc3 and displaying the .pdf file on my one of page. according to architecture: Asp.net mvc3 + WCF+EF 4.1 with Azure web role+sql azure.
My pdf file generated dynamically on cloud (azure). I need to display it on my aspx page using  tag. but what should be the url need to provide to it? will this work with Azure ? or i need to download / save it dynamically in application domain temprary to assign url. which is best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a controller action which will dynamically generate the PDF file:

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    byte[] pdf = ... generate the pdf dynamically here
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

and in the view:

```
<iframe src="<%= Url.Action("pdf", "somecontroller") %>" />
```

or if you know the url of the PDF on the cloud you can directly point the `src` of the iframe to it.

Comment: since , Azure is for cloud.  then how to manage rout over the cloud if hosted server get down ?

Comment: I don't think so , I am geeting pure xml form when i am putting the generated url into address bar in browser. so need to sort out by differnt way .... any focus so far ?

Comment: @RedSwan, you need to fetch the .pdf in the controller action from Azure and return is as byte array to the view using return File(... as shown in my answer. Then in the view you could either use an iframe pointing to this controller action or an anchor.